# Filter external list fields from client

Tags: list, sharepoint, bcs, sharepoint-clientobject

BACKGROUND:

We’re developing a custom application which access SharePoint through the Client Object Model and this application need to access ECT (external content type) lists defined in SharePoint using the OM (Object Model). This application is a product that should be usable with most SharePoint installations and configuration and cannot have prior knowledge of External Lists.

When there are no filters set up for the ECT, SharePoint returns all the available items in the list (given the number is below the threshold). The moment we define a filter for this ECT, SharePoint return only the items after this filter is applied (probably correct behaviour from SP).

PROBLEM:

We need to be able to search this ECT list (non-filtered) based on text entered by a user in a search box. At the moment there seem to be no way to change the filter SharePoint applied when returning the values to the calling object.

I.e. I have 10 items in my ECT list (1,2,3…10). Each Item has 3 columns (ID, Name, Description). After setting up a filter for the ECT list, SharePoint return items 2, 3 & 6 when I ask SharePoint for a list of items.

No the user does a search the matches the description of item 7. How can I search/filter the list to return the item that match my search query?

I’ve been running in circles trying to solve this, but nothing seem to work. I tried setting the CAML query as well as the LoadQuery as defined in both http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/how-to-query-external-lists-on-the-client-side-using-caml/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464384.aspx but nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had this problem. Let me tell you there is no way of doing this.
Even in Server object model, there was an option to change the filters of the default view but then the SPList will return 0 items once the filter is applied.
The funny part is once your code runs & you open the list in SP UI, you can see the actual modified list. But the same cannot be queries in the object model.

Looks strange. I guess if you modify the SPList (ECT based) in this instance, then you can only get results in the next instance (like in next page refresh.....)